# Do UNIX message queues maintain order of messages?

Tags: unix, mqueue

If, under UNIX/Linux/BSD/OSX, I use this sequence of APIs in Application A:

```
    msgq_id = mq_open(  full_queue_name,
                        O_RDWR | O_CREAT,
                        S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG,
                        &msgq_attr);
    mq_send(msgq_id, ptrData1, len1, 0);
    mq_send(msgq_id, ptrData2, len2, 0);
    ...
```

and this sequence of events in Application B:

```
    mqd_t open_res = mq_open(full_queue_name, O_RDONLY);
    ...
    mq_receive(...)
    mq_receive(...)
```

... do I have a guarantee that the message queue maintains the order of the messages?
That is, that Application B will receive the data from ptrData1 first, and then the data from ptrData2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man mq_send` on linux (emphasis added):

> The  msg_prio  argument  is  a  non-negative integer that specifies the priority of this message.  Messages are placed on the queue in decreasing order of priority, **with newer messages of the same priority being placed after older messages with the same priority.**

So yes, you have a guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

You get message that is oldest one of highest priority. So if you send all with same priority, you always receive them in same order.